# Does the JqueryUI Tab ever fire the Jquery 'remove' event?

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

My JQuery special event is not firing when using Tabs.

I have a JQueryUI Tab implementation, all bound with Knockout. 
I also have code to do some remove items from the viewmodel when the Jquery 'remove' event is fired but it never triggers when moving between tabs.

Does the JqueryUI tabs ever fire the Jquery 'remove' event?

```
$.event.special.formunbind = {
        remove: function(o) {
            if (o.handler){
                o.handler.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    };

$(element).bind('formunbind', function(){
                    ko.cleanNode(element);
                });
```

Answer found. Tabs do fire the special event 'remove'. The issue I had was with some jquery/jqueryui versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found. Tabs do fire the special event 'remove'. The issue I had was with some jquery/jqueryui versioning.